# Migrating UI strings

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, migrations

Is there an automated migration for UI strings (Locale module) from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8?

I have a Drupal 7 site in English and French. Some of the French strings used in the user interface have been customized (on /admin/config/regional/translate/translate). Can those customized strings be automatically migrated to the Drupal 8 site?